# Should I add a hint to my question?

Tags: discussion, hints

I have a puzzle that is months old: [Find the hidden message!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70382/find-the-hidden-message)

The solution can basically be broken down to three steps, the first was already done by [Joe-You-Know](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/48593/joe-you-know), the third should be pretty easy. But apparently nobody knows the second step.
I personally don't consider it extremely hard, but that might be because I think in a certain way. A hint might make it too easy

Should I wait even longer, hoping that it might be asked one day in the far future (which is definitely possible), or should I give a hint, risking that I might make it too easy?

(This question sort of comes down to "Are old posts usually completely forgotten after a while or is there any significant activity on months old questions?" But there might also be other factors.)

Comment: Also: Yes, I could put a bounty on my question, which attracts more people. But since I only have 131 rep., I would like to consider other other options first.

Comment: Related: [Unanswered puzzle - leave, self-answer or write a postmortem?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6019) (including self-answer) and [How long should I wait before providing the answer to my riddle?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2799) (including adding hints)

Comment: @AndrewT. I would even consider that second link a possible duplicate target. I didn't find it in my own research before. And the first linked question has a comment pointing to the "Necromancer" tag, so I should definitely leave the question open (and possibly unchanged) for at least half a year, I think.