# General question: Is there a FAQ? Specific question: is it allowed that puzzles lead to other websites?

Tags: discussion

Like the title says; Is there a general FAQ for the Puzzling Stack Exchange? And where do I find it?

Specific question 1: I have a puzzle that leads to an external website (online escape room). Is that allowed? Or should all puzzles be solvable without leaving Stack Exchange?

Specific question 2: Is it somehow possible to contact other players through stack exchange?

Comment: There's a [meta-tag:FAQ], but it's not very densely/consistently populated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, welcome to the site :) Here are the answers to your questions:

0. The site's [help](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help) page contains many FAQs, which should hopefully answer many of the basic questions you might have.
1. Re external sites, I recommend reading [this answer](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4993/37714) by @GentlePurpleRain to a previous meta question. In it they mention that the goal of this site...

> ...is to become a repository of good questions and answers... Questions that simply link to another website are basically just advertising, and are not within the scope of SE.
>
> Even if the entire question was posted on Puzzling.SE, but required a link to an outside website in order to solve the puzzle, that doesn't help anyone who finds this question in the future, after the linked-to site has rotted away. At that point, the post will be essentially useless, since there will be no way to solve the puzzle.

(There are two main issues here - the aims of the site, and the need for puzzles to be self-contained. Have a read of the original post for further discussion points.)

2. The site has a variety of [chat rooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=puzzling.stackexchange.com) that can be used for specific purposes. Our general-use chat room is [The Sphinx's Lair](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair). If a user has recently posted a message in the room they can be 'pinged' using the '@' handle and their username. Of course, if your question relates to a specific user's question or answer on another post, you can contact them publicly merely by adding a comment beneath the relevant post.
   If you require private correspondence, some users provide alternative contact details (e-mail addresses, social media profiles) in their profile page, and it is also possible to set up [private chat rooms](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5879/can-we-use-private-chat-rooms-for-collaborating-on-puzzles) within the site for particular legitimate purposes.

If you have any further questions I'm sure someone would happily reply to a general message in The Sphinx's Lair. I hope you enjoy the Puzzling experience!